# Ctools wizard back button with #action

Tags: 6, forms, chaos-tool-suite

I'm trying to build a multi-step form with Ctools that will submit to another website upon completion (a hosted payment page). On the last form page, I have set the `#action` property in the form array to allow it to submit to this other website. My issue however is that this seems to affect the Back button behavior on this form page and directs me to the website I specified in `#action` when clicked, which is obviously not desired.

Are there additional settings I can tweak to make the Back button behave correctly with the `#action` property set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to use CURL or drupal_goto(), as I needed to submit to the hosted payment page with the POST data, and be on the actual page (something only achievable with a physical form submission).

I ended up attaching a javascript click behavior to the back button to get the desired effect. Probably not the best solution, but it created the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the `#action`, then add some `curl()` code to your `#submit` callback function for the final step.

Trickier, sure, but it'll work without messing up the form caching for Drupal.

Comment: Why use something like curl?

Comment: Because curl would do what @bkildow asked for, i.e. sending the form data in post to the desired location, without messing with the drupal cache, and without relying on javascript effects which can be turned off at the browser level.  drupal_goto won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add a `drupal_goto` call to redirect to the payment site in the submit handler for the completion step.